# Google Bot Crawler Issue with Codeigniter URLS

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, googlebot, crawl-errors

I received 6000+ crawler errors in my webmaster tools account. following is the one of the URL that identified as problematic URL.

http://www.example.com/segment1/segment2&sa=U&ved=0CC8Q0gIoATACahUKEwiJ-Zj-oojGAhVNfLwKHTikAGM&usg=AFQjCNEbQaIDolWh4SQvTuZexjUDPDsF2g

Site is developed in Codeigniter. I allowed &,= characters in Codeigniter config.php. I only used query string for pagination like ?page=1

Concern 1: why google bot adds extra parameters in URL
Concern 2: why it begins query string with & instead of ?

Please guide me, what to do to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked all URLs in anchor tags on your website to make sure they are 100% correct including those generated by any javascript code that may be included in the website's HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The Googlebot doesn't add query string to the end of pages it indexes. There is one of two options here, either the Google SERP has a glitch on a few web servers which is adding that query string to the end of the URL (unlikely) or two two the links on your page are being either rendered in a malformed way by Code Igniter or being altered at run time by javascript which is mangling the link without you realising it. Ever since Google became capable of assessing how javascript changes page content and tracking javascript-based page changes for indexing purposes javascript based changes to pages has become even more important and a link that gets changed by javascript can still cause the exact same type of query string issues that used to be restricted to server side rendering issues.